# A First Course in Mathematical Analysis, David Alexander Brannan, ch 1, 1.6 exercises, section 1.3, problem 3

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove the inequality 
$$
3^{n}\ge2n^{2}+1
$$

for $n=1,2,\dots$

This looks like a problem which might be solved using the binomial
theorem. Recall
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{n} & =1+nx+{n \choose 2}x^{2}+\dots\\
 & =1+nx+\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}x^{2}+\dots\\
 & =1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^{2}+\dots
\end{align*}

Using the binomial theorem to expand the LHS of our original inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
3^{n}=(1+2)^{n} & \ge2n^{2}+1\\
1+2n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}2^{2}+\dots & \ge1+2n^{2}\\
1+2n+2n(n-1)+\dots & \ge1+2n^{2}\\
1+2n+2n^{2}-2n+\dots & \ge1+2n^{2}\\
1+2n^{2}+\dots & \ge1+2n^{2}
\end{align*}

This is obviously true.

Let's try another approach: induction.

Base case

\begin{align*}
3^{0} & \ge2(0)^{2}+1\\
1 & \ge1
\end{align*}

Now we suppose the normal case
$$
3^{k}\ge2k^{2}+1
$$

For the inductive step, multiple both sides by 3

\begin{align*}
3\cdot3^{k} & \ge3(2k^{2}+1)\\
3^{k+1} & \ge6k^{2}+3
\end{align*}

So it is sufficient for us to prove that
\begin{align*}
6k^{2}+3 & \ge2(k+1)^{2}+1\\
 & =2(k^{2}+2k+1)+1\\
 & =2k^{2}+4k+3\\
6k^{2}-2k^{2}+3-3 & \ge4k\\
4k^{2} & \ge4k
\end{align*}

which is obviously true. Thus our original inequality holds

$$
3^{n}\ge2n^{2}+1.
$$

Question: are there problems with either proof or style things that I could learn?

Question: For the inductive proof, did I choose the correct base case of zero? It seemed correct given the context, but I am not 100% certain.

I don't have a solution to check against. Are my proofs valid?

Comment: your proofs look basically correct; you could choose base case $0$ to prove the proposition for $0, 1, 2, ...$ or base case $1$ to prove it for $1, 2, ...$

Comment: How and why do you choose 0 or 1? For me, I chose 0 because there didn't seem to be any stated constraints on n, say by another inequality, and we are considering the natural numbers in induction. Is that proper reasoning?

Comment: you could choose whichever you like if it works, but if you're asked to prove something for $1,2,...$, there's no need to prove it for $0$

Comment: I forgot to consider the problem statement of domain for n. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proofs look basically correct.  When you did the proof by induction, you took the base case as $0$; you could have merely started with the base case of $1$, since the question asked to prove the inequality only for $n=1,2,...$.